# Rails 3.1 image asset timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm having intermittent issues with images on Rails 3.1.

The file in question is a simple PNG; all other images are working correctly. If I vist the asset path directly the image works as expected. Restarting the server (Webrick, in development) does not help. Clearing the browser cache does not help.

When I reload the page the image shows but the browser indicates it is still loading. After 30 seconds the request times out and the image is replaced with a broken image indicator.

Here are a few supporting images:

https://skitch.com/matt_darby/fahke/oops-google-chrome-could-not-connect-to-localhost-3000

https://skitch.com/matt_darby/fahkp/oops-google-chrome-could-not-connect-to-localhost-3000

https://skitch.com/matt_darby/fahkw/contact.html.haml-documents-code-protectedmethod.com-app-views-pages-vim

Comment: What shows up in the webrick logs for these requests?

Comment: Relevant lines: Started GET "/assets/phone.png" ... Served asset /phone.png - 200 OK (2ms)

Answer (score 2):

I too had this issue and Richard Hulse's comment above to his own answer: "delete the files in tmp/cache/assets and restart' fixed it for me.  Thanks Richard.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not working because you are running in production mode locally, or have digest turned on in your config.

In your view you should be using the asset_tag helper:

`%img{ :src => asset_path('/assets/phone.png') }`

This ensures that the correct path (with the fingerprint) is rendered into the view.

The code you have will work in development mode (or without digests), but will break when they are on, or in production.

If this is an upgraded app, check the [Rails asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for the correct stuff to paste into your config files.

Comment: This error is in development and unfortunately the behavior still exists when using the asset_path or image_tag helper.

Comment: That is odd because the header is showing an etag, which only shows up in production. Have you tried deleting the files in tmp/cache/assets and restarting?